# Array of integer as Scapy custom field

Tags: python, python-2.7, scapy

The packet I am trying to forge is like this:

```
p = IP()/TCP()/Unique()
```

where Unique is a new layer:

```
class Unique(Packet):
name = "Unique"
fields_desc=[ IntField("a", 0),
         IntField("b", 0),
         IntField("c", 0)]
```

I don't know how to define a field that contains an array of integer.
Is there a way to do that?
Instead of having three fields "a","b" and "c", I'd like to have one field that contains the three integers.

Since 3 is a variable number, another possible approach I could use is to have *n* IntField where n is variable, but I don't know how to do that either and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the `FieldListField` is the scapy aquivalent to what you are searching for. It defines an array/list of any number of fields of the same type.

```
class Unique(Packet):
    name = "Unique"
    fields_desc=[FieldListField("my_array", None, IntField("bla",0))]

>>> Unique(my_array=[1,2,3,4,5]).show()
###[ Unique ]###
  my_array= ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
>>> hexdump(Unique(my_array=[1,2,3,4,5]))
0000   00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02  00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04   ................
0010   00 00 00 05                                        ....
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Unique(Packet):
name = "Unique"
fields_desc=[ IntField("a", 0),
         IntField("b", 0),
         FieldLenField("num_records", None),
         FieldListField("c", None, IntField("number", 0), count_from=lambda pkt: pkt.num_records)
]
```

You need to include FieldListField and FieldLenField. 
See this documentation for more.
http://www.dirk-loss.de/scapy-doc/build_dissect.html#the-variable-length-field

Comment: It's incorrect. Size of the array is fixed, not encoded in the message as in your solution (there is no `num_records` field).